# How to retrieve the CKEDITOR.status "ready"?

Tags: ckeditor

In my script, I wanted to wait for the CKEDITOR to be in state `ready` before I let my own instructions go their way. So I consulted the [CKEDITOR API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-status) and wrote the following condition:

```
if(CKEDITOR.status == "ready"){
 //execute my code when ready
}
```

However, the status never ever changes to from `loaded` to `status`. Apparently I didn even see any other state.

More task specific, I wanted to catch the moment when CKEDITOR has completed modifying the inline replacing of contenteditable="true". That's when I want to go ahead with my JS code.

Any clues?

Comment: I'm not sure that the CKEDITOR.status or the "loaded" event work in CKEditor 4 because AFAIK the "delayed loading" system is another part of CKEditor that has been lost with the introduction of the 4.x series. And even if they worked, they aren't related to the initialization of the editors in the page, you must use listeners for each instanceReady as shown in the provided answers.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you want to execute your code when the API is fully loaded, use [`CKEDITOR.loaded`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-loaded) event:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'loaded', function( evt ) {
    // your stuff here
} );
```

If you want to execute your code when **any** new instance is ready, use [`CKEDITOR.instanceReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady) event:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    // your stuff here
} );
```

If you want to execute your code when a **particular instance** is ready, then use [`CKEDITOR.editor.instanceReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-instanceReady) event:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function( evt ) {
            // your stuff here
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: hint: the editor for which the event trigger is inside `evt.editor`, the original element inside `evt.editor.element.$`

Comment: @oleq can you add how could this be done in the ckeditor5 document version?

Comment: @always-a-learner In CKEditor 5 when you call the `ClassicEditor.create( ... ).then( editor => { console.log() } )` promise chain, the editor instance is ready in the `then()` block. [Learn more](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html#creating-an-editor).

Answer (score 9):

there's no `ready` status in CKEDITOR, you can use `loaded` like:

```
if ( CKEDITOR.status == 'loaded' ) {
    // The API can now be fully used.
    doSomething();
}
```

or use `instanceReady`, like:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt){ 
   //ready
  //do something
});
```

Comment: yes, there is only these below, in the sequential order. However, I wanted to catch the moment when CKEDITOR has completed modifying the inline replacing of contenteditable="true". Any clue.
    unloaded: the API is not yet loaded.
    basic_loaded: the basic API features are available.
    basic_ready: the basic API is ready to load the full core code.
    loaded: the API can be fully used.

Comment: @feder in that case you could use 'insanceReady'

Answer (score 2):

As @Sudhir pointed out, there is a slight difference between the direct attribute value and the instanceReady method.

- Use the event listener if you demand to be notified when CKEDITOR has not only completed its loading process, but also has completed the entire after-processing. In particular the HTML replacement and injection.