# Can not set CKEditor value; setData fails

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I can not set a value for CKEDITOR. Below is what I tried:

```
<textarea id="fckAciklamaIcerik" name="fckAciklamaIcerik" class='ckeditor' rows="5" runat="server">
</textarea>
```

---

```
CKEDITOR.replace('fckAciklamaIcerik');
CKEDITOR.instances.fckAciklamaIcerik.setData("sdda dasdsada");
```

When I try to run this, I get an `Browser Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined`

Why won't it work?

---

Sorry unresolved problems. .
How can I do..Waiting for your help.Thanks..

sb.Append("");
                sb.Append("").Append(item.UrunAdi).Append("");
                sb.Append("").Append(item.Fiyati).Append("");

function tableclickEvent(Description) {
            alert(Description)

```
        //No alert in calling problems..
        //Data coming from the description you want to print the CKEditor..

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Explain in brief.

Comment: Downvoters: why the downvote? As a long time CKE user this seems very clear to me. (If it was because of the extra tags or grammar, you could have just edited it yourself...)

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/a/18464877/1485219.

Comment: Why don't you set the content of the textarea just before the CKEDITOR.replace call? that way it will always work as expected and the editor will have to do the initialization of the contents once.

Answer (score 4):

If you run them so quickly together, most likely the CKEditor replace hasn't finished by the time you try to run `setData` (`.replace` is asynchronous). To test that this is the issue, try to run setData in the developer console of your browser after CKE has initiated.

If it is the case , then I suggest you watch for the `InstanceReady` event and do the `setData` in there, something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.fckAciklamaIcerik.setData('<p>sdda dasdsada</p>');

    // You can also get the editor from the event
    // evt.editor.setData('<p>sdda dasdsada</p>');
});
```