# CKEditor - Get Element by Id or Class

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to get an element with his ID or Class but with no success...

> Cannot read property 'getById' of undefined

I follow instructions here : [CKEDITOR docs GetById()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.document-method-getById)

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ckeditor_init();
});

var $textarea = $('#tiny_mce_block').find('textarea').attr('id');
function ckeditor_init() { // This works
    CKEDITOR.replace($textarea, {
        language: 'fr',
        allowedContent: true,
    });

    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea]; // This works
    var $dataCkeditor = editor.getData(); // This works

    var el = $(editor.document.getById('2')); // This doesn't work !

    console.log(el);
}
```

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/395/

In my `$dataCkeditor = editor.getData();` I have this:

```
<span class="st" id="1" data-time-start="0.29" data-time-end="1.259" data-time-moy="0.1938">mardi </span>
<span class="st" id="2" data-time-start="2.048" data-time-end="5.406" data-time-moy="0.10832258064516">qualité sécurité efficacité </span>
```

How can I select an element either by an ID (in my case `"2"`) or by a Class (in my case for example `"st"`) and after get the `"data-time-start"`  ?

thanks !

Comment: Can you fiddle your code?

Comment: Put `$textarea = $('#tiny_mce_block')` inside `$(document).ready`. That's its sole purpose.

Comment: I did that but same problem

Comment: @MokshShah : http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/395/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `instanceReady` event (see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461206/how-to-retrieve-the-ckeditor-status-ready/18464877#18464877)):

http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/LjggqL1m/

```
function ckeditor_init() { // This works
    CKEDITOR.replace(textarea, {
        language: 'fr',
        allowedContent: true,
        on: {
            instanceReady: function() {
                var editor = this;
                var data = editor.getData();
                var el = $(editor.document.getById('2'));

               alert(el);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You could also get interested in [`editor#contentDom`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) event, which fires each time editor's DOM is loaded, i.e. on `editor.setData()`.

Comment: Thanks Dude !! It works for me ! How to get the content of "el" ? and how can I do for select every element who are the Class .st  and then get their attribute (data-time-start) ? thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the line which sets the `$textarea` value *inside* the DOMReady handler, otherwise the value will be `null` as the element will not be available in the DOM when the code is executed. Try this:

```
var textarea; 
$(document).ready(function () {
    ckeditor_init();
    textarea = $('#tiny_mce_block').find('textarea').attr('id');
});

function ckeditor_init() {
    CKEDITOR.replace(textarea, {
        language: 'fr',
        allowedContent: true,
    });

    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[textarea];
    var $dataCkeditor = editor.getData();
    var el = $(editor.document.getById('2'));
    console.log(el);
}
```

Note also that the `$` prefix is primarily used in javascript to denote variables holding a jQuery object. As the `textarea` var only holds a string, I have removed the `$` for consistency.

Comment: I did what you told me but always the same problem "Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

```
    var textarea;
$(function () {
  textarea = $('#tiny_mce_block').find('textarea');
  ckeditor_init();
});
function ckeditor_init() {
 for(var i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++){
    CKEDITOR.replace(textarea[i]);
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[textarea[i]];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have assigned/stored CKEditor as global variable.

In HTML file:

```
<div id="maineditor"></div>
```

JS File.

1. Here [getById](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_document.html#method-getById) || [find()](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-find) || [findOne](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-findOne) methods useds
2. Custom config also loaded
3. JQuery Method to find Element
4. Startup focus trigged

   ```
   var GlobalEditor =null; 
     $(document).ready(function () {
      editor_initialize_events();

      //Here Find Element id/Class and It's return CKEditor DOM Element || 
       var _byId= CKEDITOR.document.find('#I1');
       var _byClass= CKEDITOR.document.findOne('.myClass');  
      // You can find element by Global varibale
       var _byId= GlobalEditor.document.find('#I1');
      // JQuery
      var el = $(GlobalEditor.document.getById('2').$);
    });    
    function editor_initialize_events() {    
       GlobalEditor = CKEDITOR.replace('maineditor', {
          customConfig: DOMAIN_ROOT + "ckeditor/config6.js",
          startupFocus: true
        });
   }
   ```